# Facebook: Comment to User's post using my facebook app's page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm developing a Facebook app where the app post a picture to user's wall after the user grant required permissions.

However according to Facebook's [privacy policy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill) they don't allow our facebook apps to post anything to user's wall which haven't explicitly entered by the user(neither as the text of the post nor as a comment to that same post).

But I need to let the people who see the post on user's wall to know where the user got it from(a link preferably).

So is there a way to post a comment to the generated post in the user's wall as my facebook app's page??(So that the comment is not posted by the user and does not violate facebook's policy)

Grateful for any help.

Comment: Have the user share a link to your page. And put OG tags on it so an image show up

Comment: Tried that. But facebook review team asked to remove that as well. Any text the user share, has to be entered by user him/herself.
We cannot even put our content and let the usr to edit it before posting.
The most we can do is to suggest/ask the user to enter the text we want.

Comment: That why you share a link. Sharing a link is allowed. You don't put the link in the message. You put the link in the link field

Comment: @WizKid I have already included share feature where the user can share link of my page. But weather to share or not is up to the user himself. That's why I wanted to know if there is a way to include my app's link in the automatic post to user's wall

Comment: You are not allowed to automatically post